# How to write Scheme (R5RS languages) program to count max depth (not using max function)?

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

Here's what I have for the depth program, but how to do it without max function (only use define, lambda,quote (‘), car, cdr, cons, cond, eq?, and equal?)?

```
(define depth
     (lambda (expr)
        (cond ((null? expr) 0) 
              ((list? (car expr)) 
               (max (+ 1 (depth (car expr))) (depth (cdr expr)))) 
              ((null? (cdr expr))0) (max (depth (cdr expr))))))
```

input: ((id = id + id)(if bool then (if bool then ( id = id + id ))(id = const / const)(id = id + id))(while bool (id = id - const)(id = id - id)))

Should output: maximumdepth: 2

Comment: I don't think the max depth of your example is "2"; you are closing it with at least three ")))".  Isn't it 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can always implement your own `my-max` and use it instead of the built-in `max` procedure:

```
(define (my-max a b)
  (if (> a b) a b))
```

You'll have to do basically the same comparison, one way or another, for finding the maximum depth - so it's ok to refactor it to a helper procedure. Notice that it wouldn't be a good idea to in-line the comparison, because that would entail evaluating twice the recursive calls - better stick to using a helper procedure, be it `max` or `my-max`.

Also, the second call to `max` is unnecessary in your code - if there's only one value, why do you need to find the maximum?

Comment: Is it possible to use car and cdr to do it?

Comment: @Layla what do you mean? for finding the biggest between two numbers only a comparison and a conditional are needed, `car` and `cdr` are used for manipulating lists. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Not sure what is the easiest way to count the depth, can you give me an example?

Comment: so for your my-max function, do you mean something like (define (my_max a b)
  (cond
   ((> a b) a)
   (b)))

Comment: @Layla at each step in the recursion, add 1 to the maximum depth of all recursive calls up to that point, bearing in mind that the list is made of atoms and lists

Comment: I don't think “if” is allowed in R5RS.

Comment: @Layla _of course_ it is! (see [link](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-2.html#%_toc_%_sec_4.1.5), section 4.1.5). What kind of Lisp dialect does _not_ have `if`?

Comment: Never mind, i messed up with other functions. (define my-max
    (lambda (a b) 
      (if (> a b) a b))) This one is the same, right?

Comment: THX, but I still have problem with my code. From the example, when input like (depth '((id = id + id)(if bool then (if bool then ( id = id + id ))(id = const / const)(id = id + id))(while bool (id = id - const)(id = id - id)))), it should get 2 for the answer, but I always get one more...

Comment: @Layla you should add 1 to the result of the max, currently you're finding the max of the depth+1. I hope this works, and if this answer was helpful for you please don't forget to accept it by clicking on the check mark to its left ... this has been a very long chat!

Comment: So you mean when I write the output code, I should do -1 there?

Comment: @Layla yes, that's one valid option